# How to pass selected dropdown value in ajax ( JSP )?

Tags: ajax, jsp, dropdown

I

> n my web application i am using a dynamic dropdown for selecting
>   class,division and student_id. When selecting the class the division
>   dropdown fills according to the class selected.. Simmilarly in the
>   student_id the dropdown fills by getting the class and the division.

My problem is that i can't pass the class value and the division value at the same time to the jsp page..

**My Home.jsp. code is ..**

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
 <html>
      <head>  
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
      var xmlHttp  
      var xmlHttp


      function showdivision(str){
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
      xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
      xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      if (xmlHttp==null){
      alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
      return;
      } 
      var url="divisionn.jsp";
      url +="?passclassname=" +str;
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = divisionChange;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }




      function divisionChange(){   
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("division").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }   
      }



      function showstudid(str){

          var select = document.getElementById("class");
var classvalue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
        xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      if (xmlHttp==null){
      alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
      return;
      } 
      var url="studid.jsp";
      url +="?passdivision=" +encodeURI(str);
      url +="&passclass=" +encodeURI(classvalue);

      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = studidchange;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }


      function studidchange(){   
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("studid").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }   
      } 



      </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
      <table border="1">
      <tr><th>Class</th><th>Division</th><th>studid</th></tr>
      <tr><td>
      <select name='class' onchange="showdivision(this.value)">  
       <option value="none">Select</option>  
    <%
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo","root","password");  
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select class from class1");
 while(rs.next()){
     %>
      <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>  
      <%
 }
     %>
      </select> 
      </td>
      <td id='division'><select name='division' >  
      <option value='-1'></option>  
      </select>
      </td>
       <td id='studid'> <select name='studid' >  
      <option value='-1'></option>  
      </select>   
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </body> 
      </html>
```

**Divisionn.jsp code is..**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String classs=request.getParameter("passclassname");  
 String bu="<select name='division' onchange='showstudid(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Select</option>";  
 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo","root","password");  
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select division_no from class1 where class='"+classs+"' ");  
   while(rs.next()){
   bu=bu+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(1)+"</option>";  
   }  
 bu=bu+"</select>";  
 response.getWriter().println(bu); 
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }

 %>
```

**studid.jsp code is...**

```
   <%-- 
    Document   : divisionn
    Created on : Nov 26, 2016, 11:13:27 AM
    Author     : Jithin
--%>


<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String division=request.getParameter("passdivision");  

String classs=request.getParameter("passclass");  



 String bu="<select name='division'><option value='-1'>---Select--</option>";  
 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo","root","password");  
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select studid from class1 where division_no='"+ division+"' and class='"+ classs+"' ");  
   while(rs.next()){
   bu=bu+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(1)+"</option>";  
   }  
 bu=bu+"</select>";  
 response.getWriter().println(bu); 
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }

 %>
```

This code is not working .. the problem is with the code which am passing the selected class name..

```
function showstudid(str){

          var select = document.getElementById("class");
var classvalue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
        xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      if (xmlHttp==null){
      alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
      return;
      } 
      var url="studid.jsp";
      url +="?passdivision=" +encodeURI(str);
      url +="&passclass=" +encodeURI(classvalue);

      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = studidchange;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }
```

Can anybody help me find a sollution .. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass multiple parameters via the URL you will need to use proper URL encoding.

```
var url="studid.jsp";
url +="?passdivision=" +encodeURI(str);
url +="&passclass=" +encodeURI(xclass);
```

Note that additional parameters are separated by & and the encodeURI function will URL encode your data.

Also consider using prepared statements as your SQL query has an obvious SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: The code is working but I'm unable to get the selected value from dropdown (Class value) . That is while passing the class name. The xclass value is unable to get. I have updated my code please see to it

Comment: Jithin, you didn't set your id attribute on the select box to class you only set the name so getElementById will just return null. Add id='class' to your select element and it should work.